# DOM manipulating HTML - icon nested inside button tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dom

I'm building a todo list right now and wondering about the usage of innerHTML.
If I want an icon inside of a button tag:

```
btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
```

which is `<button><i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i></button>` am I right?

What is the difference between the above and below?

```
btn.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
```

Comment: Different operator. Can't you see it??

Comment: @AlonEitan I know. I was asking which one is doing the nested tag

Answer (score 0):

First one replace everything inside the button add new icon

Eg if you have a button with a name "click" the name will be replaced by new icon

In second case an icon will be added to after the name "click"

Comment: So the second one is nesting inside the button tage?

Comment: you have a button like this <button>click</button> after the second operation button equal to like this <button>click<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i></button>

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
```

this line of code will replace the `innerHTML` for `btn`

```
btn.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
```

this line of code will append `<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>` into the `btn`, but when `btn` is empty, it have the same effect as `btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';`

Some simple demo here:

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

btn1.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
btn2.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
btn3.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
```

```html
<body>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <button id="btn1" >Something Inside</button>
  <button id="btn2" >Something Inside</button>
  <button id="btn3" ></button>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between the 2 assignment statements

var name *= (equals)* **sets** the value to whatever you want

```
var name = "blaqkippah"
console.log(name)
blaqkippah

var age = 23
console.log(age)
23
```

(you have already declared variable *name* so no need to declare it again with **var** keyword)

```
var name = "blaqkippah"
console.log(name)
blaqkippah
```

How += works with strings is it joins them
It's a shorter way of writing

```
name = name + "blah"

name += "deemyBoy"
console.log(name)
blaqkippahdeemyBoy // no space inserted as I wrote += "deemyBoy" not += " deemyBoy" 
ie. when joining 2 strings using += (or any other method) you have to manually add a 
space

var b = 'banana'
b
"banana"
b += ' apple'
"banana apple"
b
"banana apple"
b = 'apple'
b
"apple"
```

**Numbers** behave differently *+= becomes the plus/addition operator* adding to what's already stored in b
(with numbers you can also do -= (minus), *= (multiply) and /= (divide)

```
b = 2
console.log(b)
2
b += 3
console.log(b)
5
b = 4
console.log(b)
4
```

*minus example*

```
b-=3
console.log(b)
1
```

*divide example*

```
b /= 2
console.log(b)
0.5
```

*multiply example*

```
b *= 50
console.log(b)
25
```

Getting back to your question *I've used a js object so the innerHTML becomes a property on the object and you can see the value changing easily in the console.logs*

```
var btn = {} // decalre empty js object
undefined

btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>'; // assign value
console.log(btn)
{innerHTML: "<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>"}
btn.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
console.log(btn);
{innerHTML: "<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i><i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>"}
btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg">go back to original</i>';
console.log(btn);
{innerHTML: "<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg">go back to original</i>"}
```

I hope this is a more thorough explanation